# Android Multiple geofence alerts come even when user is at one place

Tags: android, android-geofence

I have made an application that alerts user when he enter/exit a particular place with the help of geofence api. now problem is that when user is inside a building then multiple geofence alerts(Enter/Exit) come after some time interval even user is at same place. Any suggestion to overcome this problem?

```
GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);     
    builder.addGeofences(geofenceList);
```

Comment: Please stop prefixing your questions with the tag 'discussion-board', it isn't suitable for the topic of your questions and stackoverflow isn't a discution board either.

Comment: maybe you have set `Dwelling` also in transition types?
post your `GeofenceBuilder` and `Service` Code anyways

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. This is how geofencing works - it depends on cellular network and wifi networks you're near to. Those signals come and go and quite often you get false positives.

Comment: But  documentation as mention to provide ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. then why it picked the location from cellular network?

Comment: As you can see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html it "ALLOWS an app to access precise location." It does not says it will get precise location, it just permits app to use it.

Comment: Hi, when geofence trigger it provide the location for which it is trigger. i am  in my home some time gofence trigger for a location which is 25 km from my home which is very- very far distance from my home. any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed solution to this issue. Having said that, you can try out below methods to minimize the false alarms :

1) You must make use of the DWELL transition and LOITERING DELAY. This way, you will only get trigger if the user is in that particular geofence for an amount of time as declared by loitering delay.

Note: When I say 'use DWELL', I mean that you should do both: set DWELL transition as the initial trigger as well as filter for DWELL transition in your service when you receive the trigger.

2) Force the user to set a radius as big as your application can work with. I have tested with radius of upto 200 meters resulting in false alarms. So ask yourself the question: Will it make sense in my app if the user has to set a radius of min 0.5km ?